# list posts of two post types in a single template

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query

I have two post types. One is `post` & other one is `event`. Both sharing same categories & tags. I am listing the posts by `archive.php`. Now I am listing the posts as general by two different templates like `archive.php` / `archive-event.php`. But now I want to list them in a single template with mixing the posts and order by date.

So any one would help me in this regard.

Comment: Use `pre_get_posts` to add `post` and `event` types to archive pages

Comment: How to set two post types in that function. Could you please explain this?

Comment: Do you need to display them in archive.php. Or in a page.php type template. Or in where?

Comment: I need to list them in `archive.php` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comments, you must use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to add custom post types to archive pages.

One thing you must keep in mind here though, you have two archive pages here, archive.php and archive-event.php, so `is_archive()` is going to return true on both, which will alter both pages. You will need to exclude archive-event.php from your function. To do this, you'll need to make use of [`is_post_type_archive()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) to check and exclude that specific page

For all the possible parameters you can use with `pre_get_posts`, go have a look at [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
function cpt_in_archive($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_archive() && $query->!is_post_type_archive( 'event' )) {

      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'event' ) );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );

   }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts' , 'cpt_in_archive' );
```